# Android Seekbar to mix two colors rgb codes

Tags: android, rgb, background-color, seekbar, android-seekbar

What would be the best way to use a seekbar to mix two colors? My seekBar starts in the middle and a mixed color is displayed to a imageview (Average of red1,green1blue1,red2green2,blue2)When the seekbar is moved to the left it should move more towards the color (red1,green1,blue1,) then if moved to the right it should go more to the color (red2,green2blue2).Here is my code hope i explained it well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.bignerdranch.android.colormixer.MixedColorScreen"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_mixed_color_screen">




<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="278dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView3"></SurfaceView>

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/surfaceView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progress="255"
    android:max="510" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Your Color"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />
```

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.colormixer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MixedColorScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
private SeekBar mySeekBar;
private TextView seekText;
SurfaceView img;
private static final String TAG = "MYTAG";
private int red1,red2,green1,green2,blue1,blue2,
                        newRed,newGreen,newBlue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mixed_color_screen);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mySeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);


    Intent i = getIntent();

    red1 = i.getIntExtra("red1",150);
    green1 = i.getIntExtra("green1",150);
    blue1 =i.getIntExtra("blue1",150);
    red2 = i.getIntExtra("red2",150);
    green2 = i.getIntExtra("green2",150);;
    blue2 = i.getIntExtra("blue2",150);



    Log.i(TAG,"LOGING COLORS RED =" + red1 + red2 + "GREEN = " +
            green1 + green2 + "BLUE = " + blue1 + blue2);
    img = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView3);
    newRed = (red1+red2)/2;
    newGreen = (green1 +green2)/2;
    newBlue = (blue1+blue2)/2;
    Log.i(TAG,"RGB =  " + newRed +"  " + newGreen + "  " + newBlue);

    img.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(newRed, newGreen, newBlue));

    mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new   SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            Log.i(TAG,"ONPROGRESSCHANGES");
            seekText.setText("SHOWING VALS- myprogres = " + mySeekBar.getProgress() + "/Max = " + mySeekBar.getMax() + "METHOD PROGRES = " + progress);
            //red1,green1,blue1 ;
            //red2,green2,blue2;

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            Log.i(TAG,"ONSTARTTRACHINGTOUCH");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            Log.i(TAG,"ONSTOPTRACKING");
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Did you try https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=multi+color+seekbar google search